# WSL 2 Installing Linux failed, error code: 0x80370114

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed PowerShell and WSL using the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

However, when attempting to `wsl --install kali-Linux` from PowerShell, I'm getting an error `0x80370114`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Windows subsystem feature was disabled, I fixed it using these cmds below.

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart 

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

OR

Press start and search `Windows Features` then tick mark the following:
[image]

Comment: Worked for me on a brand new Windows 22H2 installation.

Comment: this didnt work for my Ubuntu 22.04 app but it did make my old ubuntu app (16.04) on windows 11 faster. i still get error though on the 22.04 app: `WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.`

Comment: Doing so didn't work for me. I enabled "Windows Hypervisor Platform" as well, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Confirm I had to enable the HyperV features for WSL2 to install.

Comment: Indeed, Hyper-V was the key for me. `Virtual Machine Platform` was not necessary (Windows 11).

Answer (score 2):

**One-liner that includes enabling:**

- Hyper-V
- Virtual Machine Platform Windows
- Subsystem Linux

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

Enable "Code Flow Guard (CFG)" for vmcompute.exe

```
 1. Click Start and search "Exploit protection settings"
 2. Switch to "Program settings" tab along the top
 3. Add/Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
 4. Click "Edit"
 5. Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck/check "Override system settings" **(CFG must be ON for this app!)**
```

You will need to restart for changes to take effect.

```
shutdown /r
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, some good news and bad news.

First, the good - from a couple of searches that resulted in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4626), [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8430#issuecomment-1210292949), and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/wsl-2-installing-linux-failed-error-code/bae391d1-4215-4d93-b0c4-3d96404a7c74), I *believe* the error that you are receiving is due to an incorrect setting in Windows *Exploit Protection*.

Check in *Windows Security* -> *App & Browser Control* -> *Exploit Protection Settings*:

- In *System Settings*, *Control Flow Guard (CFG)* should be "On" (in my case, it is "Use default (On)".
- In *Program Settings*, there should be entries for:

  - `C:\Windows\System32\vmcompute.exe`
  - `C:\Windows\System32\vmwp.exe`

  Both should have *Control Flow Guard* set to:

  - *Override System Settings*
  - *On*
  - *Use Strict CFG*

There are some reports that turning these *off* corrects the problem, but that's probably more of a "patch" than a true resolution.

Hopefully that will resolve the `0x80370114` error.

Now the bad news ...

When I last checked a few days ago, the version of Kali that is installed via `wsl --install` is still so old that it won't even update.  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680495/432493) for details and potential solutions.

It's best if you can install from the Store.

Comment: This didn't work but I found the solution using these cmds:
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: Making both "Use Strict CFG" is what made it work for me in Windows 11. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As there is some issue on my current OS (Windows 11) about, I've been able to find a solution by setting the version of WSL to the 1 (from the 2).

```
wsl --set-default-version 1
```

This made the whole to be working again, **on before I uninstalled the Linux OS** from my system (from the *Control Panel - Add or Remove Component*) and also **removed the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature** itself as well (from the *Control Panel - Turn Windows Feature On or Off*).
**After on I added again the feature and then installed the Linux OS** by:

```
wsl.exe --install Debian
```

Thanks to [m-shahbaz-kharal on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3054#issuecomment-705991287)

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me, what did the trick was simply updating windows. There wasn't even a relevant update, I had to search for any and then after executing it ubuntu started working. Saw this as an answer to the same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1753996/how-to-fix-fresh-wsl-install-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error-0x80370?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the same answer, was submitted against another question, you should flag as a duplicate instead of submitting an answer indicating another answer submitted by somebody else, answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer worked on Win 10, not sure about 11*

##### Summary

Another reason this can happen is that the *Hyper-V Host Compute Service* (`vmcompute`) is disabled, so it can't start.

##### Details

The *Windows Features* that you need are indeed only *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (obviously) and *Virtual Machine Platform*, the latter of which also installs some *Hyper-V* components, but there is no need to install *Hyper-V* directly:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then look in `Services` and make sure the *Hyper-V Host Compute Service* is not `Disabled` and start it:
[image]

Now start your WSL distribution and the error should disappear.

##### Reasoning

A lot of people report that they get this error after an update, or after uninstalling or having some virtualization setup in the past. It's possible that the service got disabled but not removed. Then, re-installing did not help, like in my case. All sorts of solutions that people have like enabling *Hyper-V* directly, or removing and installing it, or various updates and restarts, or [stopping security software from blocking it](https://superuser.com/a/1736446/542139), all enable or trigger the start of the service. In my case, none of those helped and I had to do it manually.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error (Ubuntu not Kali) and had not rebooted my computer after installing WSL. Rebooted laptop and everything seems to be going smoothly. Just a pointer for anyone landing here after a blind google search for the error, and not trying for a more advanced installation yet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).