# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114 Error: 0x80370114

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When trying to install Ubuntu under WSL Windows 11, I'm getting the following error,
no advice on stackexchange works for me:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
Error: 0x80370114 Operaci se nepovedlo spustit, proto?e nenÝ nainstalovanß po?adovanß funkce.

Press any key to continue...
```

**EDIT**

What actions should I perform to avoid this error and successfully install Ubuntu ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What actions should I perform to avoid this error and successfully install Ubuntu under WSL and Windows 11 ? I have tried virtually every advice from google.

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1736443/wsl-2-installing-linux-failed-error-code-0x80370114) Question answer doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: @user22758952 - This question can only be answered if it’s edited, having error messages in English, would go a long way